# Report on average time before first stage change

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

I am looking to generate a report which would put out a very specific timeframe which is from the stage "new" to "open - on progress", irrespectively of current stage the opportunity is in. I tried finding a solution for this, alas, to no success. The caveat is, I have zero training on Salesforce and just happen to be currently the "most tech savvy person" in my org so am tasked with figuring this out (after successfully being able to figure out process generator and the like)

What management is looking to get is a quantifying report on how long two different record types needed before they changed from the stage "new" to "open - in progress", irrespectively of how often the stage changed in the meantime and which stage the opp is currently in and I am wondering whether there is a halfway "easy" way of doing this, either via a dashboard or a report?

Thanks a mill for any pointers as to where I need to be looking at...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this pretty easily with the Opportunity History Report Type.

Create a new report of this type, and then add filters for From Stage, To Stage and Record Type to the report, setting them to the appropriate values. Add the Stage Duration field to the report, and that will show you how long the Opportunity was in the From Stage before changing to the To Stage.

Comment: Thank you for the input, that seems to kind of work, alas, stage duration is a value in days, I'd need it in hours (or minutes) :/ .   maybe they SHOULD get a real SF admin...

Comment: You might do better then, creating a field on Opp and a Process to populate it. If Opps always start in New stage, you could calculate difference between NOW() and CreatedDate when Opp goes to Open - In Progress.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your continued support - would this be an opportunity custom field? I tried puzzling this together, but am not sure where to even start with this. I would create a field "StageDuration" with the Date/Time formular `NOW()-DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDateTime__c)` but am not sure a) how to trigger population thereof in processgenerator und b) how to have this report on minutes instead of datetime. However, as I am not expecting you to do this for me, I reached out to Salesforce, in the hopes they will be able to assist!